# Why does my HTML have a large margin at the bottom when the screen is on tablet/mobile mode?

Tags: html, css

The bottom of the footer has a large margin/space. How do I remove it? Using `margin-bottom:0"` doesn't seem to work. How should I eliminate the margin at the bottom so that it will no longer have a negative space at the bottom?

```css
/*General*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen');
.wrapper {max-width: 630px;margin: 0 auto;position: absolute;justify-content: center;align-items: center;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;margin: 0 auto;}


/*Header*/
#header .navbar .navbar-header a{color: white;font-size: 25px;font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;}
#header .navbar-inverse {background-color: #2C3E50;border-color: #2C3E50;}
#header .navbar {border-radius: 0;}
#header .navbar-nav > li > a {color:white;}
#header .navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}
#header .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {color: white;}


/*Content*/
#content .content-content {position:relative;}
#content .content-content .responsive-image{width: 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;z-index:0;}
#content .content-content h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;color: #2c3e50;font-size: 50px;z-index: 2;text-align: center;font-weight:bold;}
#content .content-content input{display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;-moz-box-sizing: content-box;box-sizing: content-box;padding: 10px 20px;border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px;font: normal medium/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: rgba(0, 142, 198, 1);-o-text-overflow: clip;text-overflow: clip;background: rgba(252, 252, 252, 1);-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);-webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);-moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);-o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);margin-bottom: 10px;width: 70%; display: flex;margin:0 auto;}
#content .content-content input:focus {border: 1px solid #018dc4;-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;-webkit-transition: all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);-moz-transition: all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);-o-transition: all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);transition: all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1); margin-bottom: 10px;width: 70%;}
#content .content-content h1{margin-bottom: 60px;}
#content .content-content .content-username{margin-bottom: 10px;}
#content .content-content .btn{display: inline-block;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align: middle;-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;border: 1px solid transparent;padding: .375rem .75rem;font-size: 1rem;line-height: 1.5;border-radius: .25rem;transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;box-sizing: content-box;cursor: pointer;font-family:  "Questrial", Helvetica, sans-serif;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);text-overflow: clip;background: #2c3e50;box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #5a80a5;width: 75%;display: block;margin:0 auto; text-align: center;margin-top: 40px;height: 40px;font-size: larger;}

/*Footer*/
#footer .footer-user{width: 100%;text-align: right;display: block;padding: 10px 20px;background: #2c3e50;text-align: right;box-sizing: border-box;color: white;font-size: 30px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;margin-bottom: 0px;height:100px;}
#footer .footer-user .footer-name{color: white;display: inline-block;font-size: 20px;font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;padding-top: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;overflow: auto;margin-top: 25px;}
#footer .footer-usericon{padding-bottom: 25px;display: inline-block;overflow: auto;}
/*Responsiveness*/

/*Desktop*/
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('http://www.wallpapershdbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/black_background_pattern_light_texture_55291_1920x1080.jpg');}
.wrapper{top:100px;}
}

/*Tablet*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('http://www.wallpapershdbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/black_background_pattern_light_texture_55291_1920x1080.jpg');}
.wrapper{top:20px;}
#content .content-content h1{margin-bottom: 20px;font-size: 39px;}
#content .content-content input{width: 50%;}
#content .content-content input:focus{width: 50%;}
#content .content-content .btn {width: 54%;margin-top: 20px;}
}

/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('http://www.wallpapershdbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/black_background_pattern_light_texture_55291_1920x1080.jpg');}
#content .content-content h1{margin-bottom: 20px;font-size: 24px;}
#content .content-content input{width: 40%;height:14px;}
#content .content-content input:focus{width: 40%;}
#content .content-content .btn {width: 47%;margin-top: 20px;height:27px;}

}

/*Custom*/
@media screen and (max-width: 574px) 
{
#content .content-content .responsive-image{background-image: url('http://www.wallpapershdbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/black_background_pattern_light_texture_55291_1920x1080.jpg');height:250px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Cute wrap</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cute wrap</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="content-content">
   <img src="img/bg.jpg" class="responsive-image">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Login to Cute wrap</h1>
    <input class="content-username" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
    <input class="content-password" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
    <button class="btn">Login</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <div class="footer-user">
   <p class="footer-name">Username Goes Here</p>
   <img class="footer-usericon" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678110-sign-info-128.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using capital M for margin-bottom: 0;?  Are you using a stylesheet for this or are you adding it inline?

Comment: im not using a capital m for it and i have a stylesheet

Comment: M is just a typo sir

Comment: In desktop mode you cant see the margin at the bottom but when you start putting it on tablet/mobile mode, the margin will appear at the bottom